# Why Jboss JCA adaptor throws Invalid Column Type SQLException while calling callables setObject method?

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jca

I am facing below exception only when trying to use JBoss JNDI (connection pool) to insert / update the record where as the fetch is working fine.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10495)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9974)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10799)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:6097)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:241)
>           at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setObject(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:1064)
>           at com.test.PkgTracker.startTracker(PkgTracker.java:67)

```
java.sql.CallableStatement ocs = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN ? := pkg_tracker.start_tracker(?); END;");
ocs.registerOutParameter(1, ObjTracker._SQL_TYPECODE, ObjTracker._SQL_NAME);
ObjTracker myPTracker = new ObjTracker(conn);
myPTracker.setValueObject(pTracker);
ocs.setObject(2, myPTracker); //Exception throws here
```

ObjTracker.java

```
private static int[] _sqlType = { oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER,
oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER,oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR,java.sql.Types.CLOB, java.sql.Types.CLOB, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR,oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP };

private static ORADataFactory[] _factory = new ORADataFactory[31];

MutableStruct _struct = new MutableStruct(new Object[31], _sqlType, _factory);
```

later _struct used to set / get the attributes of VO object.

Fix:

Its due to oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP where as the type has Date only. Though all other datatypes have flexible to convert between Number / BigDecimal / Long, but Date and Timestamp not.

Comment: What is `ObjTracker`?

Comment: ObjTracker for creating MutableStruct.